# iis express running site without debug (ie running all the time while vs is open)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

My app for ages would keep runing even when I wasn't debugging in VS 2010. Now it only runs when debugging. It was really nice for it to run even when not debugging before?

Any ideas why this might have stopped, I miss it working nicely?

Answer (score 14):

I have noticed that in VS 2013 that if you uncheck 'Enable Edit and Continue' that it will work.

Comment: Right click on project > Properties > Web > uncheck Enable Edit and Continue

Comment: This option is not available in Visual studio 2015 community.. I am facing the same issue without any workaround

Answer (score 1):

You can start it manually from the command line, either by site name or application pool:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Ah, will it start and stop as you debug? Or just keep running, and you switch into the process when you debug? I wonder why it changed behavior?

Comment: Sorry, can't remember if VS launches a new process on debug. Try it. If it does, you can just attach to the existing process in order to debug from VS (tip: Bind a shortcut key to the attach-to-process dialog box)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue to. Here is the blog post I wrote on how I solved it

http://www.radicalgeek.co.uk/Post/12/starting-up-iis-express-for-a-specflow-and-selenium-webdriver-test-run