# Why my site service is still running when I stop it from VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have ASP site with simple WCF service that I can run from Visual Studio for debugging purposes. Site starts and runs on IIS Express on specific port and I can see metadata in browser by entering `http://localhost:35168/mySrv.svc`. I stop VS , but this page is still available and refresh has no influence on that. Looks my service is running? Why? How to stop it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iis express running site without debug (ie running all the time while vs is open)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268239/iis-express-running-site-without-debug-ie-running-all-the-time-while-vs-is-open)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS Express, you can try to enable edit and continue option.
Right click your project > click Properties > select the 'Web' tab on the left > check the Enable Edit and Continue checkbox.

Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18794676/2283405

Answer (score 0):

if you closed your VS window without terminating your process/server port it will keep running.
if this is your case you just need to terminal all process/server on that port by using

```
sudo kill
```